# Add JSONarrays in multiple Arraylists in anddroid [JAVA]

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I want to add Specific JSON arrays in multiple array lists..
In the below JSON structure, I just want to add robotAnswer arrays in multple arraylists:

```
"boot": [
  {
    "where": "STARTS",
    "userSuggestion": [
      "hey",
      "hello"
    ],
    "robotAnswer": [
      "Hello. I am Robot",
      "Hi",
      "How are you?"
    ]
  },
  {
    "where": "CONTAINS",
    "userSuggestion": [
      "how are you"
    ],
    "robotAnswer": [
      "I am well",
      "Im doing fine"
    ]
  }
]
```

for example i want to get arraylist result like this:

```
[ [Hello. I am Robot, Hi., How are you] , [I am well, Im doing fine] ]
```

I have tried this code:

```
 private final ArrayList<List<String>> robotText = new ArrayList<>();
 private final ArrayList<ArrayList<List<String>>> robotAnswer = new ArrayList<> 
 (Collections.singleton(robotText));


 for (int j = 0; j < arrayBoot.length(); j++) {
 JSONObject data = arrayBoot.getJSONObject(j);
 String where = data.getString("where");
 JSONArray answerArray = data.getJSONArray("userSuggestion");
 JSONArray robotArray = data.getJSONArray("robotAnswer");

 ......///

int arrSize = robotArray.length();
  for (int i = 0; i < arrSize; ++i) {
    String word = robotArray.getString(i);
    List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
    words.add(word);
    robotText.add(words);
    robotAnswer.add(robotText);
}
```

by using this code i'm getting result which is i don't want:

```
[[Hello. I am Robot], [Hi], [How are you?], [im well], [im doing fine]
```

Comment: You should how you obtain robotArray and where your ouput is coming from

Comment: I edited my question with some more code

Comment: Can you show what's the content of  `JSONArray robotArray = data.getJSONArray(AppConfig.robotAnswer);`. I have the feeling it's flat.

Comment: JSONArray robotArray = data.getJSONArray("robotAnswer"); you can check JSON structure, its arraylist of robotAnswer

Comment: you want like this? `[ [Hello. I am Robot, Hi., How are you] , [I am well, Im doing fine] ]`

Comment: @NikunjParadva yes bro, but i just checked NobanHasan 's answer. but his code returning string like this: " Hello. I am Robot, Hi., How are you  , I am well, Im doing fine,  " and i converted string to arraylist now its working

Comment: @NikunjParadva you can also share you code , so i will not need to convert the string in arraylist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code should be like below this code. in robotAnswer list you will get your desire list.

```
private final ArrayList<List<String>> robotText = new ArrayList<>();
 private final ArrayList<String> robotAnswer = new ArrayList<> 
 (Collections.singleton(robotText));


 for (int j = 0; j < arrayBoot.length(); j++) {
 JSONObject data = arrayBoot.getJSONObject(j);
 String where = data.getString("where");
 JSONArray answerArray = data.getJSONArray("userSuggestion");
 JSONArray robotArray = data.getJSONArray("robotAnswer");


 String sentence = "";
 int arrSize = robotArray.length();
  for (int i = 0; i < arrSize; ++i) {
    String word = robotArray.getString(i);
    sentence = sentence + word+",";
 
}
  
  robotAnswer.add(sentence);


}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.. I changed little bit in your code to convert string to arraylist now its working fine... :)

Comment: You are most welcome. :) please give me a upvote if this is helpful ^_^